# Java DatePicker Returns Null

Tags: java, swing, javafx, datepicker

I have two JPanels in a JTabbedPane. Each of the JPanels have two DatePickers. When I wrote the first JPanel, each of the DatePickers worked fine. However, once I added the other two DatePickers in the other class, the first two DatePickers no longer work. When I try to return the date selected (with datePicker.getValue()) the DatePickers in the first class return a value of null. The later DatePickers, though, work just fine.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Specific code in BudgetTab class (problematic class):

```
jfxpanel = new JFXPanel();
jfxpanel2 = new JFXPanel();
jfxpanel.setBounds(460, 152, 265, 40);
jfxpanel2.setBounds(460, 276, 265, 40);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        initFX(jfxpanel);
        initFX2(jfxpanel2);
    }
});

budgetPanel.add(jfxpanel);
budgetPanel.add(jfxpanel2);

private void initFX(JFXPanel panel){
        Scene scene = createScene();
        panel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private void initFX2(JFXPanel panel){
        Scene scene = createScene2();
        panel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene(){
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        dp = new DatePicker();
        dp.setEditable(false);
        root.getChildren().add(dp);
        return scene;
    }

    private static Scene createScene2(){
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        dp2 = new DatePicker();
        dp2.setEditable(false);
        root.getChildren().add(dp2);

        return scene;
    }
```

Specific code in Timeline class:

```
startDatePanel = new JFXPanel();
        startDatePanel.setForeground(panelColor);
        endDatePanel = new JFXPanel();
        endDatePanel.setForeground(panelColor);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
            public void run(){
                initStartDate(startDatePanel);
                initEndDate(endDatePanel);
            }
        });  

public void initStartDate(JFXPanel panel){

        Scene scene = createStartDateScene();
        panel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createStartDateScene(){
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        startDatePicker = new DatePicker();
        startDatePicker.setEditable(false);
        root.getChildren().add(startDatePicker);
        return scene;

    }

    public void initEndDate(JFXPanel panel){
        Scene scene = createEndDateScene();
        panel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createEndDateScene(){
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        endDatePicker = new DatePicker();
        endDatePicker.setEditable(false);
        root.getChildren().add(endDatePicker);
        return scene;
    }
```

Comment: What DatePicker are you using? You added the javafx tag but this looks more like a Swing question. Swing doesn't provide a DatePicker out-of-the-box however, so again my question: What DatePicker are you using?

Comment: Also please show us the relevant code.

Comment: For the DatePicker, I am able to import the javafx package, then add JFXPanels (one for each DatePicker) to the swing application.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you have posted can hardly be considered minimal...

Comment: Also, sorry for messy code. The JFXPanel and the run statement is towards the beginning of each of the two classes and the methods that those run statements call are written towards the end of each class.

Comment: Why do you even need `DatePicker`? It seems they are always non-editable, and you just set the `date` property manually. Wouldn't it be simpler to have a proper `LocalDate` member, and just use a native (Swing) TextField with a `SimpleDateFormatter` to print the date into?

Comment: No. The method setEditable for the DatePicker determines whether or not you can type into the field. So when I set it to false, I made it so you can only choose the date with the DatePicker.

Comment: Also, it may help to know that when I remove the second class, the DatePickers in the first class work again. Somehow the DatePickers in the second class are conflicting with the DatePickers in the first, to cause them to return null. How could this happen?